# HTML onclick attribute with variable URL

Tags: html

Below code is for navigating to the Google Webpage when the element `<li>` is clicked.

```
<li onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">Google</li>
```

Now I have another `<li>` which goes to different websites depending on a parameter. I tried this

```
<script>
  document.write('<li onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com/mmm/yyy/' + random_variable +  'ddd/eee';" style="cursor:pointer;">Google</li>');
  </script>
```

This isn't working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's wrong with using an `<a>` tag?

Comment: You mean <a> within the <li> tag?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean. You could style it to look however you want. It's much more SEO friendly and won't give you trouble in older versions of IE

Comment: I will give that a try for sure. Any clue what I'm doing wrong in the above code though?

Comment: Don't use `document.write` - it replaces entire document. Rather set `onclick` attribute only

Comment: @Cafecorridor the first example works for me in Chrome so it's likely an issue with whatever browser you're using. Which is exactly why you should use an `<a>` tag. Either that or there's a problem somewhere else in your HTML.

Comment: @Yuriy Without document.write how do I include the HTML in Javascript?

Comment: @Cfreak First example works fine for me as well. What about the second one?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought neither worked. I'll provide an answer for you.

Comment: Instead of `document.write`, please append your `<li>` tag to some DOM element, like `<ul>`.

Comment: @Blaise I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you write down the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `document.write`. Instead you can change the attributes of the tags themselves. `onClick` is just javascript inside your code so you can replace variables

```
<li onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com/mmm/yyy/' + random_variable +  'ddd/eee';">Google</li>
```

It's a little messy. I'd personally do it with jQuery and a regular `<a>` tag

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someid').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        location.href= 'http://google.com/' + random_variable;
    });
});
```

Or if your random variable is available onload you could just replace the `href` attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someid').attr('href','http://google.com/' + random_variable);
});
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="#" id="someid">Google</a></li>
```

Comment: Your first solution works fine. I'm planning to use this one. Any drawbacks with respect to browsers?

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetElement = document.getElementById("id");
targetElement.appendChild('<li>...</li>';
```

The first line find the existing element, where you want to insert the `<li>`.
The second line insert it.